# SQL Select Multiple Tables Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have tables **article_receive** and **article_issue** along with several other tables, out of which i need to create a consumption report.

In *article_receive* i have 2 types of transactions, A JVN(Journal Voucher Entry) and PUR (Purchase Order Entry). **JVN** based entries are basically the opening balance and **PUR** are receiving.

I am facing 2 problems.

**1st**  the **price** column is returning wrong value from **article_receive** table, it should return proper price so that it can be reflected in consumption report.
**2nd** i want to calculate the stock opening balance (JVN) from **article_receive** and omit it from rest of the calculation.

Receiving table has price column for a unit

```
SELECT
    a.issuance_id , a.created_at , a.item_id , a.quantity as issuedQty,
    b.department_id , b.demand_id,
    c.title,
    d.id , d.title,
    e.price , (e.price * a.quantity) as subtotal,
    g.location_id , g.imported
FROM 
    article_issues as a, issuances as b  , departments as c , segments as d , article_receives as e , purchases as f , items as g
WHERE 
    a.issuance_id = b.id AND c.id = b.department_id AND d.id = b.segment_id AND e.transaction_id = f.id AND g.id = a.item_id
AND 
    b.created_at BETWEEN '2019-05-01' AND '2019-05-15' 
AND 
    a.quantity > 0
```

Current out put of above query is

```
ISS19050001 2019-05-02 12:11:37 GRL0157 24.00   40  VQM19050003 Vaccum Metalizing   1   Lamps   5.00    120.00  88  0
ISS19050001 2019-05-02 12:12:15 GRL0245 1.00    40  VQM19050003 Vaccum Metalizing   1   Lamps   5.00    5.00    88  0
ISS19050001 2019-05-02 12:12:55 GRL0254 1.00    40  VQM19050003 Vaccum Metalizing   1   Lamps   5.00    5.00    88  0
ISS19050001 2019-05-02 12:14:06 GRL0684 2.00    40  VQM19050003 Vaccum Metalizing   1   Lamps   5.00    10.00   88  0
ISS19050001 2019-05-02 12:14:42 GRL4182 12.00   40  VQM19050003 Vaccum Metalizing   1   Lamps   5.00    60.00   88  0
ISS19050003 2019-05-02 12:31:05 GRL0035 1.00    2   ELC19050003 Electrical  12  General 5.00    5.00    273 0
ISS19050020 2019-05-02 12:39:48 GRL0157 60.00   1   MLD19050001 Moulding    3   Resin   5.00    300.00  88  0
ISS19050020 2019-05-02 12:40:00 GRL0218 2.00    1   MLD19050001 Moulding    3   Resin   5.00    10.00   88  0
ISS19050020 2019-05-02 12:40:13 GRL4262 12.00   1   MLD19050001 Moulding    3   Resin   5.00    60.00   88  0
ISS19050021 2019-05-02 12:40:46 GRL0008 3.00    1   MLD19050002 Moulding    3   Resin   5.00    15.00   88  0
ISS19050021 2019-05-02 12:40:55 GRL1760 4.00    1   MLD19050002 Moulding    3   Resin   5.00    20.00   274 0
```

Sample Data from **article_receive**

```
217 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   JVN19050217 1595.00 26.00   1595.00 41470.00    1   May 1st Opening Stock - Entered through JVN for new General Inventory Program   2019-05-01 09:57:36 2019-05-01 09:57:36
1443    GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   PUR19050053 3600.00 30.42   4907.00 109512.00   1       2019-05-22 11:58:13 2019-05-22 11:58:13
```

Sample Data from **article_issue**

```
1   VQM19050003 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050001 24.00   1571.00 0.00    1   2019-05-02 12:11:37 2019-05-02 12:11:37
7   MLD19050001 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050020 60.00   1511.00 0.00    1   2019-05-02 12:39:48 2019-05-02 12:39:48
23  AAL19050001 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050018 24.00   1487.00 0.00    1   2019-05-02 08:05:10 2019-05-02 08:05:10
36  PHR19050001 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050025 60.00   1427.00 0.00    1   2019-05-02 08:12:49 2019-05-02 08:12:49
75  AAL19050003 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050105 24.00   1403.00 0.00    1   2019-05-03 11:56:21 2019-05-03 11:56:21
85  AAL19050007 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050130 24.00   1379.00 0.00    1   2019-05-04 12:04:40 2019-05-04 12:04:40
107 MLD19050008 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050039 72.00   1307.00 0.00    1   2019-05-04 10:11:52 2019-05-04 10:11:52
166 MLD19050009 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050080 48.00   4859.00 0.00    1   2019-05-03 13:12:49 2019-05-03 13:12:49
173 MLD19050015 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050085 72.00   4787.00 0.00    1   2019-05-06 13:18:08 2019-05-06 13:18:08
181 MLD19050017 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050087 72.00   4715.00 0.00    1   2019-05-07 13:23:22 2019-05-07 13:23:22
189 MLD19050020 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050089 72.00   4643.00 0.00    1   2019-05-08 13:25:42 2019-05-08 13:25:42
197 MLD19050023 GRL0157 HAND GLOVES ( WHITE )   ISS19050092 72.00   4571.00 0.00    1   2019-05-09 13:28:36 2019-05-09 13:28:36
```

Comment: @jarlh . . . You left out another reason:  More likely that strangers on the web will bother to understand your query and answer your question.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.